# Superconducting parameter phase in BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: superconductivity

I am trying to derive the AC Josephson effect in the second quantization formalism starting from the BCS Hamiltonian for the superconductors and a tunneling Hamiltonian but I am confused about the phase of the order parameter. I understand how it is derived in the GL formalism, but I don't know how to make the connection with BCS.

Is the phase coming from the second Josephson equation, $\partial_t \phi = \frac{1}{2e}V$, something intrinsic to the order parameter when we write it on the BCS Hamiltonian, or does it come from the chemical potential term of the Hamiltonian, $-\mu N$ when we gauge it away going to the interaction picture?

Comment: The phase is the phase of the order parameter $\Delta$. Please open Tinkham's book, the derivation you try to do is done explicitly. Then come back with an explicit question if any remains.